# Make maps on item frames unrotatable

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to put a map on an item frame, and I have used this command in order to make it unbreakable by players in adventure mode.

```
data merge entity @e[type=item_frame,sort=nearest,limit=1] {Invulnarable:1b}
```

But I do not want it to be rotatable, I have tried many nbt tags for the command above, but none of them seem to work.

Any solution on how can I make items on an item frame unrotatable?

Comment: Why not just put something like an armor stand in front of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag you are looking for is `{Fixed: 1b}`. From the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_Frame#Entity_data):

> **Fixed:** 1 or 0 (true/false) - true to prevent it from dropping if it has no support block, being moved (e.g. by pistons), taking damage, and placing an item in it, removing its item or rotating it.

In addition, the command you provided in the question won't work because you misspelled `Invulnerable`. But with `Fixed`, you don't need the invulnerable command at all.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, I know I misspelled Invulnerable, but I retyped the command in order to understand the idea.